# Multiplicative regression

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I am trying to estimate a regression model on a data set with one continuous dependent variable (y) and three categorical independent variables (x1,x2,x3). For example imagine y is the price you pay for a smartphone and x are three features (say color, size and storage space).

My assumption is that each feature represents a multiplicative factor relative to an (unknown) baseline price. So if the baseline price for your phone is 100 a red color would increase this by 25%, a large size decrease it by 50% and high storage space increase by 75%. This means the final price of the phone would be 100 x (1+0.25) x (1-0.50) x (1+0.75) = 109.375.

The problem is that I only know the final price (not the baseline price) and the individual features. How can I estimate the multiplicative factors that go along with these features? I have written a brief simulation in R below to illustrate this problem.

Thanks for your help with this,

Michael

```
x_fun   <- function() {
    tmp1                <- runif(N)
    tmp2                <- cut(tmp1, quantile(tmp1, probs=c(0, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3)))
    levels(tmp2)        <- seq(1:length(levels(tmp2)))
    tmp2[is.na(tmp2)]   <- 1
    as.factor(tmp2)}

N       <- 1000

x1      <- x_fun()
x2      <- x_fun()
x3      <- x_fun()

f1      <- 1+0.25*(as.numeric(x1)-2)
f2      <- 1+0.50*(as.numeric(x2)-2)
f3      <- 1+0.75*(as.numeric(x3)-2)

y_Base  <- runif(min=0, max=1000, N)
y       <- y_Base*f1*f2*f3

output  <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)
rm(y_Base, f1, f2, f3, N, y, x_fun, x1, x2, x3)
```

Comment: The baseline price would be the price with features 1,1,1. Ie the lowest factor value for each variable. This is what R takes as baseline as well if you use `glm` models. To refer to your example: how would you define a price for a phone with no size and no screen? People usually take the phone with the lowest specs as baseline.

Comment: @niczky12 It may not be that simple. I believe by that logic the base price is -278.7348 instead of 499.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your model is there just one base price for all N observations?

Comment: @WeihuangWong I think base price is that variable `y_Base` going from 0 to 1000 with a mean of approx 500

Comment: I'm not sure if this is set up correctly -- shouldn't the mean of `y_Base` be significantly lower than the mean of `y`? It seems that `y` has a larger range but the means are equal (+/- small random variation).

Comment: @WeihuangWong Base price is supposed to be theoretical minimum price of a good with none of its features/attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this **if you know the base levels of your factors**:

```
N       <- 1000
set.seed(42)
x1      <- x_fun()
x2      <- x_fun()
x3      <- x_fun()

f1      <- 1+0.25*(as.numeric(x1)-2)
f2      <- 1+0.50*(as.numeric(x2)-2)
f3      <- 1+0.75*(as.numeric(x3)-2)

y_Base  <- runif(min=0, max=1000, N)
y       <- y_Base*f1*f2*f3

str(x1)

output  <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)
#rm(y_Base, f1, f2, f3, N, y, x_fun, x1, x2, x3)


output[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")] <- lapply(output[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")], relevel, ref = "2")

fit <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = output, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
summary(fit)
predbase <- exp(log(output$y) - predict(fit, type = "link") + coef(fit)["(Intercept)"])


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = y_Base, y = predbase, output[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")]),
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ x1 + x2 + x3) +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, color = "dark red")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a co-incidence since `y` and `y_Base` are so close (which I think may be a mistake in the simulation) but when I run this the predicted base (`predbase`) has a mean (501.3) that's almost identical to the final price (501.9) instead of the base price (512.3).

Comment: `y` and `y_Base` are not close at all. I'm not sure why you focus on mean values here. AFAIU the goal is getting the base prize for each observation.

Comment: @WeihuangWong I do not understand what you mean by "constant base prize". Wasn't the goal to get the base prize of each observation?

Comment: By not close you're saying that 512 is not close to 500 relative to the impact of the product attributes?? Wouldn't you expect the base *price* (not prize, *price*) to be less than the final price by definition? and why is your predicted mean the one of the final price rather than the base price? Like I was saying the base and final prices should not be almost the same and **the base price has to be lower by definition**. Also **this estimates the final price not the base price**.

Comment: @Hack-R I don't understand your objections and the last sentence is simply wrong. Compare these: `output[521, ]; 
y_Base[521]; 
predbase[521]`.

Comment: @Hack_R Note that the way the data is generated means each factor is below 1 for group 1 and above 1 for group 3. Thus, the expected value of the price is not different from the mean base price.